# Excel 2013 Vlookup - Not Working

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have the following table:

```
short_NM Prod Name        Prod Network          Prod Cluster    Prod Node        DR Network                    DR Cluster        DR Node              Cluster Name
App 1   SERVER_NUM_1    SERVER_NUM_2.domain.net SERVER1111CL    SERVER1111N1    DR_SERVER_NUM_1.domain.net  DR_SERVER_0001CL    DR_SERVER_0001N1    SERVER_NUM_SVR
App 1   SERVER_NUM_2    SERVER_NUM_3.domain.net SERVER2220CL    SERVER1111N2    DR_SERVER_NUM_2.domain.net  DR_SERVER_0002CL    DR_SERVER_0001N2    SERVER_NUM_SVR
App 2   SERVER_NUM_4    SERVER_NUM_4.domain.net SERVER1100CL    SERVER1100N1    DR_SERVER_NUM_3.domain.net  DR_SERVER_0003CL    DR_SERVER_0011N1    SERVER_NUM_2_SVR
App 2   SERVER_NUM_5    SERVER_NUM_5.domain.net SERVER2300CL    SERVER1100N2    DR_SERVER_NUM_4.domain.net  DR_SERVER_0004CL    DR_SERVER_0011N2    SERVER_NUM_2_SVR
```

If you put this table into Excel (starting at A1), put 'SERVER1111N1' into A8, then put the following in B8 `=VLOOKUP(A8,B1:I5,8,FALSE)`  The result will be '#N/A'.  However, if you put `=A8=E2` in cell A9, you get 'True'.

Why does vlookup not work in this scenario?

Comment: I assume you're trying to look up the DR Node (8th column). You need to start LOOKUP arrays from the column/row that contains the lookup value, so in this case, where you're looking for the the Prod Node value, the lookup range should be E1:I5 and should offset by only 3 columns.

`=VLOOKUP(A8,E1:I5,4,FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

When you use a vlookup, the first cell in the range you specify `B1:I5` is the column that HAS to match the value you are looking `A8`.  The value you are looking up `SERVER1111N1` is over in Column `D` so vlookup is failing.

Instead:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,D1:I5,8,FALSE)
```

Or:

```
=INDEX(I2:I5,MATCH(A8, D2:D5, 0), 1)
```